while reading Image I am getting TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not JpegImageFile
def convert_pdf_to_images(file_path, scale=300/72):
    pdf_file = pdfium.PdfDocument(file_path)
    page_indices = [i for i in range(len(pdf_file))]
    renderer = pdf_file.render(
        pdfium.PdfBitmap.to_pil,
        page_indices=page_indices,
        scale=scale,
    )
    list_final_images = []
    for i, image in zip(page_indices, renderer):
        image_byte_array = BytesIO()
        image.save(image_byte_array, format='jpeg', optimize=True)
        image_byte_array = image_byte_array.getvalue()
        list_final_images.append({i: image_byte_array})
    return list_final_images

    def display_images(list_dict_final_images):
    all_images = [list(data.values())[0] for data in list_dict_final_images]
    for index, image_bytes in enumerate(all_images):
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_bytes))
        plt.title(f"----- Page Number {index+1} -----")
        plt.imshow(image)
        plt.axis("off")
        plt.show()

def extract_text_with_langchain_image(list_dict_final_images):
    image_list = [list(data.values())[0] for data in list_dict_final_images]
    image_content = []
    for index, image_bytes in enumerate(image_list):
        image = Image.open(BytesIO(image_bytes))
        loader = UnstructuredImageLoader(image)
        data = loader.load()
        raw_text = data[index].page_content
        image_content.append(raw_text)
    return "\n".join(image_content)

def extract_text_with_langchain_pdf(pdf_file_path):
    loader = UnstructuredFileLoader(pdf_file_path)
    documents = loader.load()
    pdf_pages_content = '\n'.join(doc.page_content for doc in documents)
    return pdf_pages_content

pdf_file_path = "/content/8db57286447743.5d9a14b409864.pdf"

# Convert PDF to images
pdf_images = convert_pdf_to_images(pdf_file_path)

While run this code in google colab, I am getting error like
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-13-d7aae7e80233> in <cell line: 56>()
     54     return "\n".join(image_content)
     55 
---> 56 text_with_langchain_image = extract_text_with_langchain_image(convert_pdf_to_images)
     57 print(text_with_langchain_image)
     58 

11 frames
/usr/lib/python3.10/genericpath.py in isfile(path)
     28     """Test whether a path is a regular file"""
     29     try:
---> 30         st = os.stat(path)
     31     except (OSError, ValueError):
     32         return False

TypeError: stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not JpegImageFile
    

How to solve this error ?
I am trying to read the text of the image. for that i have write this code. I have a pdf that contain images. first it will convert pdf to images and that it will read a text from that image. I am getting error in line "data = loader.load()"
Here is the reference file :
reference file

The dump tells you that you need to provide a file name, not an JpegImageFile object. So provide a string with a file name not a JpgeImageFile .

pdf_file_path = "/content/8db57286447743.5d9a14b409864.pdf" I have given it like this

... but the error message tells you that what you mean to pass as path is not a string ... and the code you provided is not the code which gives the error ...

I have copy whole code. Can you please check it now.

What is pdfium?

I have install that library "pip install pypdfium2" and than imported that "import pypdfium2 as pdfium"

Here is the reference file : "https://github.com/keitazoumana/Medium-Articles-Notebooks/blob/main/OCR_Content_Extraction.ipynb"

The code you have provided runs on my machine without producing an error (I have changed the string to a PDF file). How to see the images? Make sure the file you try to load is actually a PDF file and not a jpeg file with wrong extension ...

I can also see the images of the PDF file. So there is nothing wrong with your code.

for disply the image : "display_images(pdf_images)"

I rename the pdf name and it is working fine now. Thnak you

Glad to hear it works now for you. So it's time to delete the question ... Questions caused by typos or other similar issues do not qualify as questions on stackoverflow ... so there will be no answer and it is not of interest to future visitors.
